# Converting IntegerField to ForeignKey from recovered database in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working with a MySQL database that I connected to my django project (using `python manage.py inspectdb > app/models.py`) but it's not reading the relationships correctly. The ForeignKeys are IntegerFields so I cannot use the handy Django ORM lookup. Here's an example:

```
class ChileStudents(models.Model):
    """ simplified version of the model """
    otec = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) # Here's the issue
    # More stuff goes here
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'chile_students'


class Otecs(models.Model):
    """ Also a simplified version """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'otecs'
```

As shown in the example above, the IntegerField points to the OTEC id, this is a simple one-to-many relationship. I tried converting the field into a ForeignKey like this:

```
otec = models.ForeignKey('Otecs', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True, db_column="otec_id")
```

But when migrating it just sets the column `otec_id` to `NULL`.

Is there any way I can "convert" the field into a ForeingKey?

Comment: If you use `inspectdb`, then the models are typically *unmanaged* (so `managed = False`, since these already exist).

Comment: I changed it to `True` so I can add some CRUD to the app. Is that wrong? Nobody will be editing the DB but me

Comment: but CRUD operations can still be done, the idea is that you no longer *migrate* the database (so create the table, add/remove a column, etc.), since the table *already* exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that the name of the database column is `otec` with `db_column='otec'`:

```
class ChileStudents(models.Model):
    otec = models.ForeignKey(db_column='otec', blank=True, null=True)
    # More stuff goes here
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'chile_students'
```

But since the table already exists, you can not make it `managed = True`, since then Django will try to create the table at the database side, create/remove columns, etc. Since here the table already exists, you can not let Django handle that, since then it will aim to create a table that already exists.

Comment: You're the boss! Thanks a lot